# Преобразование в Map c помощью stream api

Tags: java

Есть список `logList` состоящий из элементов класса

```
class Log {
    String ip;
    String user;
    Date date;
    Event event;
    String number;
    Status status;
}
```

содержащий геттеры

```
 public Map<Integer, Integer> getAllSolvedTasksAndTheirNumber(Date after, Date before) {

    Map<Integer, Integer> list= logList.stream()
            .filter(log -> log.getNumber()!=null)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(log -> Integer.parseInt(log.getNumber()),
                    log -> getNumberOfAttemptToSolveTask(Integer.parseInt(log.getNumber()),after,before)));

    return list;
}
```

Метод `getAllSolvedTasksAndTheirNumber` должен вернуть `Map<Integer, Integer>` где ключ элемент `getNumber()`, а значение значение возвращаемое методом `plas (Intereg int)`. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться со Stream api.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> list = logList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        log -> Integer.parseInt(log.getNumber()),
                        log -> plas(log)));
В plas() передаёте что вам нужно, и то, что вернётся, будет value.
```

Comment: Использую Intlelij idea выдает ошибку при попытке написать лямбда внутри toMap.

Comment: И не даёт вписать log.

Comment: Конкретнее, куда не даёт вписать log? В метод plas()? Значит он у вас принимает не объект класса Log, а что то другое.

Comment: Нет, с plas все нормально. Если помешу внутри скобок toMap, то log высветит красным. См. Мой пример

Comment: Выложите сюда этот вариант.

Comment: Сейчас не могу, пишу с телефона, но в принципе мой вариант в вопросе.

Comment: Может быть конфликт с фильтром или .map?

Comment: Ну да, .map здесь не нужен. После него остаётся только стрим интеджеров getNumber();

Comment: public Map<Integer, Integer> getAllSolvedTasksAndTheirNumber(Date after, Date before) {

        Map<Integer, Integer> list= logList.stream()
                .filter(log -> log.getNumber()!=null)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        log-> Integer.parseInt(log.getNumber()),
                        log-> getNumberOfAttemptToSolveTask(Integer.parseInt(log.getNumber()),after,before)));

        return list;
    }